# Having trouble displaying the Ionic app icon on Samsung One UI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic5

[image]

All app icons are round but but why is the pointed icon square? I don't have any solution please give me some suggestions.

Model name: Galaxy S9
Model number: SM-G960U
One UI version: 2.5
Android: 10

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (C:\Users\Avirup Ghosh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.15
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.15
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.15
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 22 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 1.7.1) : 1.5.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\Avirup Ghosh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.16
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: You need to check your icon file.

Comment: @StefaniTotokotsopoulou Thank you, I used adaptive icons and my problem was solved